# puppeteer execute a js function on the chosen page

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

This is the analyzed page https://www.diretta.it/.

In this page the content of the following days is loaded dynamically with the js without changing the URL of the site (you can try it at the top right of the table).

Using puppeteer, with the following code

```
await page.goto ('https://www.diretta.it/');
```

it loads the contents of today's page.
Is there a way to load the page with tomorrow's content?
i have to scrape information from the matches of the following days

the function in js executable from terminal for change day is:

```
> set_calendar_date ('1')
```

Comment: have you tried just doing eval on the whole document? something like
`await page.$eval('html', () => set_calendar_date ('1'));`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [`page.evaluate()`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v4.0.0&show=api-pageevaluatepagefunction-args) function.
This function lets you run any JS function in the page context.

In simpler terms, running `page.evaluate()` is akin to opening Dev tools and writing `set_calendar_date('1')` there directly.

Here is a working snippet, don't hesitate to pass `{headless: false}` to `puppeteer.launch()` if you want to see it working with your own eyes.

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.diretta.it/');
  await page.evaluate(() => {
    set_calendar_date ('1');
  });
  await page.waitFor(500); //Wait a bit for the website to refresh contents

  //Updated table is now available
})();
```

Comment: How would this work if the function is defined within another context? Say I have an iframe that has id "main-iframe", and a function "onTest()", how would I be able to call that function then?

Comment: How would you handle the *Cannot find name 'set_calendar_date '* error?

Comment: @Анна
await page.evaluate("set_calendar_date('1')");